# Check URL exists or not By VBScript

Tags: url, if-statement, vbscript, request, exists

I want a vbscript that will check whether a URL exists or not without opening any browsers. If exists then pop up a message.
The script pattern should be like this: ( The simpler script, best script )

Usual codes here

```
Url="www.lol.com/letter.txt"
```

Codes to check whether the url exists or not

```
If exists

Msgbox("Success")

Else

Msgbox("Failed")

Wscript.Quit
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This function should do the job

```
function testUrl(url)
    Set o = CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
    on error resume next
    o.open "GET", url, False
    o.send
    if o.Status = 200 then testUrl = True
    on error goto 0 
end function
```

Call it using

```
if testUrl("http://www.example.com") then
     msgbox "SUCCESS"
else
     msgbox "FAILED" 
end if
```

Comment: Good one bro... But avast detects this script as a virus.. :(

Comment: Can't you just flag it as an exception?